# How to include assets like icons in an Angular8 library?

Tags: angular, assets, angular8

I've been trying to add some assets into an Angular 8 library.

The library was created with ng generate library and my goal is to include some icons in SVG format to be used inside the HTML component's templates.

So far I've tried to add the library's assets folder to the parent application angular.json file, but to no avail. While developing my assets, in a folder at the library source root, is unreachable. Copying the folder to the dist one once the library is built haven't work either.

What's the proper way of including assets folder into the library, just like it is done for an app? I think this is a fairly frecuent use case, since components rely on icons usually. Also a method to embed the SVG or PNG into SCSS files will be enough to solve this use-case.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I want to include SASS files that are not compiled for things like mixins and variables.

Comment: Hmm.. How about converting it to a base64 string, and access it as a static property or something? I am not sure what is the best way of handling it

Comment: did you tried include in the property scripts of your angular.json?

Comment: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/273#issuecomment-344988878

Comment: Seems like the best approach ATM is to copy your asserts manually

Comment: @Reactgular, would it be enough to use @imports? I've been able to use them in libraries without problems.

Comment: @wentjun, I was thinking in this course of action using Compass inline-img. Does somebody have a good experience with that?

Comment: Anything imported will get included in the bundles. If you want "assets" like images in your library. I think they have to copied yourself in a post build script, but Angular doesn't support library assets. So the consumer of the library has to copy from `node_modules` any files to their own `src/assets` folder.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot @Reactgular, I'll try to figure this out in an example. It would be very nice if Angular libraries can handle assets and global styles as easily as main projects, but for now I'm afraid we'll have to sort this out with some workarounds like this ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed that problem adding the SVG icons to app.component.ts using DomSanitizer and MatIconRegistry libraries.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      `icon-1`,
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/images/icon-1.svg")
    );
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      `icon-2`,
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/images/icon-2.svg")
    );
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      `icon-3`,
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/images/icon-3.svg")
    );
    .
    .
    . 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Then in the html of your component add the image as follow:

**myComponent.component.html**

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="icon-1"></mat-icon>
                <span>Icon 1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="icon-2"></mat-icon>
                <span>Icon 2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="icon-3"></mat-icon>
                <span>Icon 3</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```